# Using LINQ to get DataGridView row value where third column has specific value

Tags: c#, linq, datagridview

I'd like to get the value of a cell from a DataGridViewRow, where the value of its third  column matches.

but an exception of type System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException "Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection." has occured.

my code is as follow:

```
 for (int i = 0; i <= intranumber; i++)
        {    
           string source = (string)(from r in dataGridView5.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()  
                             where   (string)r.Cells[3].Value== intra[i].Item1
                             select r.Cells[1].Value.ToString()).First();
```

Comment: third column should be accessed by index 2: `r.Cells[2]`

Comment: No it is the fourth column..am wrong

Comment: you are counting up and including intranumber. are you sure you dont want to count not including: `for (int i = 0; i < intranumber; i++)` ?

Comment: no it all right because i have some treatments to do with a loop.. the problem is  here:   where   (string)r.Cells[3].Value== intra[i].Item1

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is intra[i].
if intranumber is the intra.count. So you must have i

Comment: No intra is a list of two string parameters

Comment: So you i = 0 or i =1  . In ur case ithink intranumber is >1